# Create text editor with line number

Tags: cocoa

What best component UI to create text editor with line number on left side ?

1. nstableview, 2 column : label and textfield
2. Textarea with array label number on left side ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I would use a custom `NSTextView` object that draws the line numbers on the left side.